# FrameBox around figure*

Tags: boxes

I am using TeXShop (3.77 on a Mac) writing a twocolumn article and would like to insert a single-column insert that consists of three short paragraphs, side-by side.  (I'd rather not switch to a full three-column style because I want to place this insert much like a figure.)

The following code works fine, as far as this goes:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\begin{center}
\color{mygray}{\sc IN BRIEF}\color{black} \\[.1cm]
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.9in} {\bf Here} is my first text, which will be several lines long
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.9in} {\bf Here} is my second text, which will be several lines long
\end{minipage}\quad 
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.9in} {\bf Here} is my third text, which will be several lines long \end{minipage} 
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

However, I would like to include all of this text in a single box, such as a framebox, and this is proving rather difficult.  I have tried creating the framebox first, and inserting the above code inside it (without success), and likewise creating the {figure*} environment and inserting the framebox inside it (again, without success).

As a minor addendum, I would also like to render the framebox in gray (rather than black).

Comment: just put an fcolorbox around your minipages (not around the figure)

Comment: @David Carlisle:  I want a *single* box around the entire set, not three (or four) around the separate texts.  (Take a look at articles in a printed issue of *Scientific American* to see the style.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. (I'll post an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\addtolength\textwidth{100pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\fboxrule{3pt}
\color{mygray}\textsc{IN BRIEF}\color{black} \\[.1cm]
\fcolorbox{mygray}{white}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1.9in}
\textbf{Here} is my first text, which will be several lines long
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.9in}
\textbf{Here} is my second text, which will be several lines long
\end{minipage}\quad 
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.9in}
\textbf{Here} is my third text, which will be several lines long
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bravo.  Thank you @DavidCarlisle.  (I actually want the box around the IN BRIEF too, but I can fix that.)